# Get Orders by Store Id

Tags: magento2.4.1, order-collection

I want to retrieve orders of a specific store? Is there any way to achieve it.
R&D just gave me methods to get store id from order or get store/customer information using order. But i have not found anything which helps me to fetch the orders collection of a specific store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor, import

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
```

and set

```
$this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
```

and if you already have a way of obtaining the store ID you should be able to call it by passing it in like:

```
public function getOrderCollectionByStoreId($storeId)
{

    $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $storeId);
     
    return $collection;
     
}
```